# Facebook API - Получить репосты

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-api

Пытался разобраться в Facebook API, но по факту так и не понял, как получить список всех постов пользователя (мне нужны посты, которые были именно репостнуты).
Все что я смог получить, это только посты самого пользователя, что мне не нужно.
Кто что знает? Для получения использую Python facebook SDK, так что можно в его формате.